# Fetch filtered tree like relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got relation between 3 tables, let's call them `tree`, `parent` and `children`.

I want to (always) fetch tree, fetch parent if it's not deleted or has undeleted children and children if they're not deleted.

Following query works with exception that it doesn't fetch the tree.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tree t
LEFT JOIN parent p ON t.id = p.tree_id
LEFT JOIN children c ON p.id = c.parent_id
WHERE t.id = 2599 
    AND (p.deleted = false OR (p.deleted = true AND pc.deleted = false));
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This on clause `ON c.id = c.parent_id` is wrong right? It should be `ON p.id = c.parent_id` or something alike. You are joining C with C

Comment: Try using only the columns you need in the `SELECT`, especially only columns from tree table and then check if it's still not returning tree.

Comment: The parent can be deleted and have undeleted children at the same time? That sounds like a broken parent-child relationship to me.

Comment: Thirsten Kettner: This actually makes sense with e.g. forum threads and replies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it looks like you're got a problem in the second join.

Also, your `WHERE` clause is going to turn those `LEFT JOIN`s in to `INNER JOIN`s:
- `NULL` is never equal to either TRUE or FALSE

I'd try something like this...

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  tree       AS t
LEFT JOIN
  (
    parent     AS p
  LEFT JOIN
    children   AS c
      ON  c.parent_id = p.id
      AND c.deleted   = false
  )
    ON  (t.id = p.tree_id)
    AND (c.id IS NOT NULL OR p.deleted = false)
WHERE
  t.id = 2599
```

`children` only get associated to `parent` is they're not deleted.

That join only gets associated to `tree` if `parent` is not deleted, or there are children *(we've already ensured that they're only included if they're not deleted)*.

***EDIT :***

I never like using `RIGHT JOIN`, but perhaps it could be more readable with it?  I don't think so, but I'll include it for completeness.

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  parent     AS p
LEFT JOIN
  children   AS c
    ON  c.parent_id = p.id
    AND c.deleted   = false
RIGHT JOIN
  tree       AS t
    ON  (t.id = p.tree_id)
    AND (c.id IS NOT NULL OR p.deleted = false)
WHERE
  t.id = 2599
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not that difficult. (EDIT: I wish I had never said this ;-) Only make sure to treat outer joined records correctly (i.e. check for null).

```
SELECT * 
FROM tree t
LEFT JOIN parent p ON t.id = p.tree_id
LEFT JOIN children c ON p.id = c.parent_id and c.deleted = false 
WHERE t.id = 2599 
AND (p.id is null OR p.deleted = false OR c.deleted = false) -- parent okay?
AND (c.id is null OR c.deleted = false) -- child okay?
```

Comment: Doesn't work - tree is not fetched if all children are deleted.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you are right. So it actually *is* that difficult :-) The problem is that I joined deleted records and removed them afterwards, rather than joining only undeleted records. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now your code doesn't join the parent that has undeleted children ;)

Comment: Darn it. Of course, I am excluding deleted parents, which I must not, because I shall show them in case of existing undeleted children. I'll update my query one more time and if that doesn't work I'd better give up. Yes, it is really not that easy...